# Width of control which has combobox set to window's width wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a control which has a `combobox` and this control is placed in a window. When I click on the dropdown of the combobox the width of the items are going out of the width of the window.
The width of the combobox in the control are set as `minwidth=600` and `maxwidth = 600`.
If I change the width here, all the places where this control is used, its width will be affected.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Laya, give us some code. Maybe, some ComboBox properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the dropdown width (and other properties ... MaxWidth) by defining a ComboBoxItem style and setting your ComboBox ItemContainerStyle to it.

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="600"/>
</Style>

<ComboBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}" />
```